# Improving Max function in R

Tags: r, max

I have a data frame like this:

```
Df <- data.frame(A=c(2,3,9,12,2,5,7,7,1,23,3,4,14,3,9,8,6,11,9,4),B=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2))
```

and my code is:

```
   #translates the column based on the counter in column B
Df %>%
  mutate(B = if_else(B == 1, "A", "B")) %>% 
  group_by(B) %>% 
  mutate(var = paste0("V",row_number())) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = B, names_from = var, values_from = A) %>% 
  rename(row_name = B)

#creates a new data frame
new <- Df %>%
  group_by(B) %>% 
  mutate(var = paste0("V",row_number())) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = B, names_from = var, values_from = A)

#extraction of the maximum value and saving in a new df
new$row_maximum = apply(new[,-1], 1, max)
complete <- new %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Pos = which(c_across(V1:V10) == row_maximum )[1])

fin <- matrix(sample(c(0:0), 50, replace = TRUE), nrow(complete))
fin <- as.data.frame(fin)

#part to improve
tab_max <- new$row_maximum
tab_max <- as.data.frame(tab_max)
fin$V14 <- tab_max
```

my question is: is there any way to improve the last part? is it possible to do the last step using the position saved in complete$Pos?

Comment: Removed the `rstudio` tag since it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: can you explain what exactly the goal is because there is a lot of hardcoded stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

fin <- Df %>%
  mutate(B = if_else(B == 1, "A", "B")) %>% 
  group_by(B) %>% 
  summarise(var = "tab_max",
         max_val = max(A)) %>% 
  select(B, var, max_val) %>% 
  bind_rows(data.frame(B = rep(c("A", "B"), 25), var=rep(paste0("V", 1:25), 2), max_val = 0)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=var, values_from=max_val) %>% 
  select(paste0("V", 1:13), tab_max, paste0("V", 15:25)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

which returns

```r
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 tab_max V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0      23   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0      14   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```